# Excel Mac macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos, runtime

Newbie just trying to make Excel (Mac) save a sheet as a PDF, which also saves the filename as a cell name. I have got it to work in my Windows Excel, but runtime error within Mac. Please help.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    pdfName = ActiveSheet.Range("G5") 'PDF name
    ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & ":" 'Use the files directory
    FileSaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("G5") 'Name the PDF file

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FileSaveName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "File Saved as " & " " & FileSaveName
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("G5")` is a cell reference, use `ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Value` to get it's value. It might help to use `Option Explicit` at the start of the module and defining all variables like `Dim pdfName As String`, it will help when it comes to line by line debugging with F8... You should be able to use the string you defined later on: `FileSaveName = pdfName`

Comment: If you are using Excel 2016, the colon is not the right path separator. You should replace the `":"` with `application.pathseparator` anyway.